# What should be the Roadmap for JAVA EE

Tags: java

I have done Java SE and want to start JAVA EE. But i am very confused, from where i have to start .So please tell me the roadmap from where to start Java EE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE is a huge umbrella of APIs to build scalable and distributed applications.
You may not need to touch subjects like EJB, JMS, JCA (Java Connector API) at this moment.

I think the most important part that you need to study now is Java Servlets and JSP (doing Java web development).

You really need to know how to build web applications by using raw Servlets and JSPs before adopting a web framework like SpringMVC, Grails, Play! ...

I heartily recommend [Head First Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516680.do).

Also have a look at [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/index.html) to see what Java EE offers in general.